# Making Doxygen read double-slash C++ comments as markup

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to set up automated [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) runs on our massive 78,000 file C++ codebase. It's doing okay with extracting basic type and hierarchy information, but I'd like to make it smarter about picking up the documentation comments that are already in place.

Most of the comments that have accumulated over the years do follow a general pattern, though not the pattern that Doxygen expected. Mostly they look like

```
// class description
class foo
{
   // returns ascii art of a fruit
   const char* apples( void ); 

   // does something to some other thing
   customtype_t baz( foo &other );

   enum
   {
      kBADGER, // an omnivorous mustelid
      kMUSHROOM, // tasty on pizza
      kSNAKE,  // oh no!
   };
}
```

Which are double-slashed, rather than the `///` or `//!` style comments that Doxygen expects.

There are far too many files to go through searching and replacing all such comments, and many of my programmers are violently allergic to seeing triple-slashes in their code, so I'd like to find some way to make Doxygen read ordinary comments as JavaDoc comments, when they're in the right place. **Is there a way to make Doxygen read `//` as `///`?**

I couldn't find any such configuration parameter, so I figure I'll need to transform the input somehow. In general the rule I'd use is:

- if there is a line containing just a
  comment, immediately preceding a
  function/class/type/variable
  declaration, assume it is a `///`
  comment.
- if there is a declaration
  followed on the same line by a `//`
  comment, treat it as a `///<`

But I don't know how to go about teaching Doxygen this rule. The two ways I can think of are:

1. Write a program as an [INPUT_FILTER](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter), which parses the input C++ and transforms `//`s into `///`s as above. But this kind of transform is too complicated to do as a regular expression, and I really don't want to have to write a full blown C++ parser just to feed input to another C++ parser! Also, spinning up an INPUT_FILTER program for each file slows down Doxygen unacceptably: it already takes over 30 minutes to run across our source, and adding an [INPUT_FILTER](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) makes it take over six hours.
2. Modify the Doxygen source code to include the above comment rules. That seems like a scary amount of work in unfamiliar code.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What about a little script that runs through the directories once, looks for `// ` (with space) in the code and turns it into `/// `? Also, if your coder are allergic against `///`, tell them to get something from the pharmacy.

Comment: You can modify the parser of doxygen so it uses `//` instead of `///` in certain places. Doxygen is opensource after all. From the FAQ: `it is probably not too hard to tweak src/scanner.l`

Comment: @Xeo If I actually checked out, modified, and checked in 78000 files just to modify the comments to a format no one likes, I'd be fired before lunchtime.

Comment: @Crashwork: Seriously, if you want to use Doxygen but refuse to accept its syntax / comment style, then something is wrong. IT doesn't matter if they hate the comment syntax, if it is necessary for the docs, they have to bear with it, period.

Comment: @Xeo : I'm trying to encourage adoption of Doxygen, but it's already a bit of an uphill battle because not everyone understands its value yet. If I try to force everyone to adopt a standard they dislike, they'll resist, I'll get pushback from the team, and eventually the whole Doxygen idea will be dropped altogether and we'll be back at no documentation. Such is the reality of working on a large programming team.

Comment: @Crash: You have my deepest condolences. :(

Comment: Given the pushback from dev, either use an INPUT filter, or copy the source code, replace the comment format, and run doxygen on the copy. A simple "sed" as filter should not cause overhead.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: You can't.

The special style of doxygen must be used, to mark a comment as documentation.

Doxygen does NOT only take comments, that precede the declaration. You also could use them everywhere in the code.

If you want to use the doxygen features, you would have to update the comments by hand, or write a script/tool that looks for declarations and preceding comments to change them.

You have to decide, choose one from the 3 solutions (your two, and the script, added as answer) or not using doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script to change comment to Doxygen style, here is a simple python script, just try it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import re

def main(input_file, output_file):
    fin = open(input_file, 'r')
    fout = open(output_file, 'w')
    pattern1 = '^\s*//\s.*'
    pattern2 = '^\s*\w.*\s//\s.*'
    for line in fin.readlines():
        if re.match(pattern1, line) != None:
            line = line.replace('//', '///', 1)
        if re.match(pattern2, line) != None:
            line = line.replace('//', '///<', 1)
        fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print 'usage: %s input output' % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(1)
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: This will also modify comments which do not immediately precede declarations -- it would change every comment, everywhere. That would generate an enormous amount of false input.   The way that INPUT_FILTER launches a new Python instance for every input file also makes the doxygen run much too slowly (the build takes over twelve hours, rather than 30 minutes).

Comment: Two points: 1. you can use regex expression to skip the comments which do not immediately precede declarations, the above script is just a simple one; 2.changing the comments styles is not need before every building of the project, just do it once, than it's not need to do that next time.

Comment: But how do I write a regex that matches any declaration? That is what  stopped me from trying this before: I can guess how to write a regex that matches simple declarations of known primitive types, like `int foo( char bar, bool baz )`, but not when each of those types may itself be a complex typedef brought in from a header file elsewhere, eg `ResultVar_t foo( CBadger &a, CPizza<Mushroom_t> b, .. )`

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the type itself, use regex to match the declaration format, eg a class declaration is differnt from a function declaration in format.